# Is it possible to run jar files in an android application?

Tags: art

I am a begginer in android and I want to develop an application which show a list of jar files to user and user can choose one of them and run it. Is it possible to run a jar file in an android application? (not as a library)
if yes, how does it run? I mean, a jar file needs to run in JVM but an apk file runs in ART.

Comment: Basic Java programs are possible, but all GUI elements used in JVM are not available on Android. Please note that app-development question are off-topic here and should be posted on stackoverflow.com instead.